# Sql Server - Matching exact ids or more

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `"messages"` table with columns: `"id"`, `"title"`,

`"categories"` table with columns: `"id"`, `"title"`,

and `"messages_categories"` link table with columns: `"message_id"`,`"category_id"`.

lets assume we have `messages` with ids of

```
1,2,3
```

and `categories` with ids of

```
1,2,3
```

`messages_categories` with data of

```
message: 1, category: 1

message: 2, category: 1

message: 2, category: 2

message: 3, category: 1

message: 3, category: 2

message: 3, category: 3
```

I want to find the exact match or more for example

if I search for category 1 i'll get messages 1,2,3

if I search for category 1,2 i'll get messages 2,3

if I search for category 1,2,3 i'll get only message 3

i'm using a lot of ids so join for every category can be too much.

I figured out I can use `"having"` statement with `"sum"` and `"count"` to find the exact rows
but it's not good enough.

Appreciate any help, Nevo.

Comment: Please clarify "i'm using a lot of ids so join for every category can be too much." Do you mean that you specify a lot of categories as input? If yes, then how many?

Comment: "exact match or more" is meanigless!  From your example, however, it looks like you want to find any and all message ids for which are in all categories in a given list?  I.e., given the list of categories (1,2) you want to know all mesages in both categories 1 and 2?

Comment: What do you mean by "to find the exact rows but it's not good enough."

Answer (score 1):

If you need "more" then use NOT EXISTS, so called *relational division with reminder*.

```
SELECT DISTINCT messages_id
FROM messages_categories r1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
        FROM 
           (SELECT 1 as cat_id UNION SELECT 2 ) S -- id of categories needed 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT *
                FROM messages_categories AS r2
                WHERE (r1.messages_id = r2.messages_id)
                   AND (r2.category_id = S.cat_id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.message_id
FROM (
   **query-that-gives-the-exact-rows-but-isnt-good-enough**
) AS x
```